# feedburner broken links within feed

Tags: http-status-code-404, feedburner

We have setup a rss feed, http://www.beautysouthafrica.com/RSS/BeautySA-RSS-Feed.aspx
and have linked it up with our feedburner account, http://feeds.feedburner.com/beautySA.

However, if you click on the links within the feedburner feed they return a 404 error. Is there a feedburner setting that I have setup incorrectly or is it the feed within the website that is causing this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a user experience this problem when logged into a Google Apps account in the browser he was trying to subscribe with. You'll get this error when the administrator of the Google Apps domain hasn't turned on the FeedBurner service for the domain.

In terms of a solution, you can have your Google Apps domain administrator turn that service on, though they may not want to. Otherwise, I think you're left with just using a different email address.